# Is there a way in Django to load a template in 'sections' or 'chunks' a sort of pagination as you scoll?

Tags: django, templates

The reason I ask is that I'm parsing a large List into a Django template, we're talking about 100,000 items being rendered into a table and it's painfully slow at loading!

or is there a method that I've completely missed?

I'm currently using {% regroup %} to group headers together.

Answer (score 1):

with the Paginator class

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

from myapp.models import Contact

class ContactList(ListView):
    paginate_by = 2
    model = Contact
```

and the template

```
{% for contact in page_obj %}
    {# Each "contact" is a Contact model object. #}
    {{ contact.full_name|upper }}<br>
    ...
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/

Comment: I have explored this option, and it does work, you are correct, but is there a way to have it all on the same page and dynamically load in as you scroll?

Comment: this concept is called infinite scroll, you have to do it with some javascript https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html

Comment: you sir are a scholar and a gent, this looks perfect!